# How can I store the value from the QTableWidgetItem to the QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt

I have a stored value from the QTableWidget which I want to store the values to the QLineEdit which is my mainWindow. Im using QVector to store the values. Is it possible to use the QVector to store and it can be pass to the MainWindow which contains all the QLineEdit

```
   void TableWidgetWindow::on_pushButton_add_clicked()
{
    addUI->portNumber(0);
    addUI->PWMPort(0);
    addUI->dutyCycle(0);
    addUI->frequency(0);
    addUI->state("ON");

    addUI->exec();
    if(addUI->click() == true){
        QStringList res = addUI->result();
        LAMP2U_Container tmp;
        tmp.pwmport = res[2].toInt();
        tmp._state = res[1];
        tmp.portnumber = res[0].toInt();
        tmp.dutycycle = res[3].toInt();
        tmp.frequency = res[4].toInt();
        containerCDB.append(tmp);

        ui->tableWidget->container = containerCDB;
        ui->tableWidget->appendData();
    }
    else
        return;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is your main window really a `QLineEdit`? Both, the question and the code are really unclear.

Comment: I suggest, that you provide a minimal reproducible example. It would help yourself and others that are willing to help you.

Comment: @BenjaminBihler same concern here,@anewor why do you say is main window, are you doing `:QMainWindow:setCentralWidget()`?

Comment: I already added sample output i want to claim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

myapp.pro

```
QT      += core gui widgets
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp mainwindow.cpp
HEADERS += mainwindow.h
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QHeaderView>
#include <QLineEdit>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

    QWidget anotherWidget;
    QVBoxLayout vLayout;
    QTableWidget table;
    QLineEdit lineEdit;
    QPushButton bt{"from the QTableWidgetItem to the QLineEdit"};
    int row = 0;

protected slots:
    void toLineEdit();

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

struct Item {
    QString portnumber;
    QString pwmport;
    QString dutycycle;
    QString frequency;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    setCentralWidget(&lineEdit);
    setWindowTitle("Main UI");

    anotherWidget.setLayout(&vLayout);
    vLayout.addWidget(&table);
    vLayout.addWidget(&bt);
    anotherWidget.setWindowTitle("Another UI");
    anotherWidget.show();

    connect(&bt, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::toLineEdit);

    int rows = 5;
    QList<Item> container;
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
       Item item;
       item.portnumber = QString::number(row);
       container.append(item);
    }

    QStringList labels{"portnumber", "pwmport", "dutycycle", "frequency"};
    table.setRowCount(rows);
    table.setColumnCount(labels.count());
    table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels);
    table.verticalHeader()->hide();

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        table.setItem(i, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(container[i].portnumber));
        table.setItem(i, 1, new QTableWidgetItem(container[i].pwmport));
        table.setItem(i, 2, new QTableWidgetItem(container[i].dutycycle));
        table.setItem(i, 3, new QTableWidgetItem(container[i].frequency));
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {}

void MainWindow::toLineEdit(){
    QString text = table.item(row++, 0)->text();
    lineEdit.setText(text);
}
```

Comment: I have another UI for that table, and my Main UI must only contain the QLineEdit.

Comment: Updated answer to have `lineEdit` as central widget and `anotherWidget`
 with the `table`.